# How can I check if a word can be created from another word without the length of the word affecting the result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make this program where if the user entered 2 words, the program could check if the 1st word could be created with the 2nd word

The issue I am running into is that it will say 'THAT WORD CAN BE CREATED' only if the length of both words are the same

For example, if word 1 was 'EAT' and word 2 was 'TEA', then the word can be created and so the program prints 'THAT WORD CAN BE CREATED'

But if word 1 was 'EAT' and the 2nd word was 'HEART', then the word should be created because the letters, 'E', 'A', 'T', are in 'HEART', but then the program prints 'THAT WORD CANT BE CREATED'

How can I resolve this to where the length of the word doesn't matter?

Code:

```
def word_checker():

    word_1 = input('Enter a word: ').upper()
    word_2 = input('Enter another word: ').upper()   

    word_1_list = [i for i in word_1]
    word_2_list = [n for n in word_2]

    word_1_dict = {}
    for char in word_1_list:
        if char not in word_1_dict:
            word_1_dict[char] = 1

        else:
            word_1_dict[char] += 1


    word_2_dict = {}
    for char in word_2_list:
        if char not in word_2_dict:
            word_2_dict[char] = 1

        else:
            word_2_dict[char] += 1


    if word_1_dict == word_2_dict:
        print("THAT WORD CAN BE CREATED")

    else:
        print("THAT WORD CANT BE CREATED")

word_checker()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the word you're trying to create is a subset of the letters you're trying to create it out of, rather than checking for equality -- this is a non-commutative operation when the lengths are different!

Using `Counter` for simplicity (it's the same idea as the dictionaries you're creating, but `Counter` makes it a one-line operation):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>>
>>> def word_checker(word: str, letters: str) -> bool:
...     needed = Counter(word)
...     available = Counter(letters)
...     return all(available[letter] >= count for letter, count in needed.items())
...
>>> word_checker("EAT", "HEART")
True
>>> word_checker("HEART", "EAT")
False
>>> word_checker("EAT", "TEA")
True
>>> word_checker("TEA", "EAT")
True
>>> if word_checker(
...     input("Enter a word: ").upper(),
...     input("Enter another word: ").upper()
... ):
...     print("THAT WORD CAN BE CREATED")
... else:
...     print("THAT WORD CANT BE CREATED")
...
Enter a word: EAT
Enter another word: HEART
THAT WORD CAN BE CREATED
```

Comment: I tried implementing this in my own code by removing the last comparison statement and replacing it with: all(word_2_dict[letter] >= count for letter, count in word_1_dict.items()). This works for the most part, but sometimes the program throws a key error, any idea why? For example if I wrote, 'hello', then 'bye', I would get the error -> KeyError: 'H'

Comment: It's because you didn't use `Counter`, which will automatically return 0 for any absent key.  If you want to do it using plain `dict`s you need to do more work.  :)  One method would be to use `get` and supply a default of 0.  Another would be to use `try/except`.  Another would be to add an extra condition to check whether the letter is in `word_2_dict` before you try to access its value.